# Setting a SQL command parameter DbType dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I seem to be gnawing at this issue, and although I can see how it *should* work, I can't seem to see the wood for the trees..

Basically I have a situation where I have a SQL 2008 stored procedure.. very basic.. simple varchar's and int's etc.
Because I am getting the value/pair data from javascript, of course I don't implicitly know the DbType to set.. I know this sounds a bit off perhaps, and I could technically add some sort of tag to the fieldname to indicate the actual type.

So right now I am trying to do the following:

(I am using the Enterprise Library Data Access Block, but db is the database object/connection object) - also the val/pairs are from a hashtable..

```
db.DiscoverParameters(cmd);
IDictionaryEnumerator de;
de = PDMdata.GetEnumerator();
while (de.MoveNext())
{
    DbType ptype = cmd.Parameters[de.Key.ToString()].DbType;
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, de.Key.ToString(), ptype, (ptype)de.Value.ToString());
}
```

For reference, the db.AddInParameter takes the Command object, param name, param type and param value..

As you can see I am trying to cast the value as correct SQL DbType.. but of course it is trying to use the normal C# Type..

Any ideas of converting the value to the dynamic SQL DbType??

Thanks in advance for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, silly me.. if I am already checking the format/data quality in the frontend/middleware, then I can (because I am using the Enterprise Library 5.0) .SetParameterValue(cmd, paramname, paramvalue) and the parameter discovery will take care of the rest...

So basically instead of using the Explicit .AddInParameter (which needs the DbType), the above solution works for me.. might for you too in this scenario.

Comment: Hi there, actually reviewing, probably nothing.. just at the time I was having issues with the datatypes and converting values to the correct types.. so in fairness your answer was as correct as my final code db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@" + de.Key.ToString(), conval) (conval was just the checked/converted value from the params collection).  So thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The `SqlCommand.Paramaters` collection has an `AddWithValue(String name, Object value)` method... so you can skip the SqlDbType altogether if you're so inclined.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.. I think I am on to something, but not quite sure of the final details.  Basically I am trying to get TypeCode of the DbType, and then when converting the param value, I am trying Convert.ChangeType(paramValue, TypeCode(Db Param)) ... but still going on that because I seem to get int32 TypeCode for an AnsiString DbType..

Again, thanks for the repsonse!

Comment: This is a handy way - but a dangerous one, too! What happens if you pass in a e.g. NULL value?? How does SQL Server / ADO.NET know what type you want to specify?? I would be very very careful with this!! I prefer to **explicitly specify** my datatypes to be on the safe side!

Comment: If you pass a null, sql treats it as a null.